# Remove " from string in array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fputcsv

I've got a HTML form, which I need to store in DB, then write it to .csv and .txt . Everything work well, except the txt output give me some bad string.

fputcsv function:

```
private function fputcsv_custom1($fp, $array, $eol)
{
  fputcsv($fp, $array, ';');
  if ("\r\n" != $eol && fseek($fp, -1, SEEK_CUR) === 0) 
  { fwrite($fp, $eol . "\r\n"); }
}
```

Controller:

```
$peoples = OnlineSz::all()->toArray();

$file = fopen("online_hotel.csv", "w+");
$file1 = fopen("online_hotel.txt", "w+");

array_keys($peoples);

foreach ($peoples as $key => $array) {
  $this->fputcsv_custom($file, $array, ';');
  $this->fputcsv_custom1($file1, $array, ';');
}
fclose($file);
fclose($file1);
```

It generates me 2 file, which separated by ; and the last value give a \r\n to new line.

The txt output is the next:

```
53;"New test";Worker;test;test;4000;test;test;06123456789;test;0;0;CC;;0;0;
```

If the string contain whitespace, it's stored by " " , how can i  remove this quotes? Or how can i replace the quotes only this column from an array?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

If i replace the space between 2 word, the quotes are not there, but what can i do if i need the space between the string?

Controller:

```
$this->fputcsv_custom($file4, str_ireplace(chr(32), '/',$user), ';');
$this->fputcsv_custom1($file5, str_ireplace(chr(32), '/',$user), ';');
```

Output:

```
53;New/test;Alkalmazott;test;test;4000;test;test;06123456789;0;0;CC;0;0;
```

But this i wrong, because the /, and if i replace it to chr(32), the quotes will be there.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use str_ireplace to remove the quotes....

```
$var  = str_ireplace('"', '', $var); //strip quotes from $var



 $this->fputcsv_custom($file, str_ireplace('"', '',$array), ';');
 $this->fputcsv_custom1($file1, str_ireplace('"', '',$array), ';');
```

You might also want to trim them of trailing spaces....

```
 $this->fputcsv_custom($file, trim(str_ireplace('"', '',$array)), ';');
 $this->fputcsv_custom1($file1, trim(str_ireplace('"', '',$array)), ';');
```

Comment: I've used the first one of your answer, but in the .txt, the quotes still there..

Comment: ? `"`  Odd.. perhaps copy the character you see and paste it into the str_ireplace('X'   It may not be a standard quote

Comment: copied, but still there in the output TXT file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fputcsv(...)` you could use `implode(";",$array);` and `fputs(...)`

But remember the csv php functions follow a certain RC standard which i can't google now. I will edit the answer later. So you are not following the standard any more.